# Error: Cannot find symbol recursion

Tags: java

My problem is that it keeps saying:

**Error**:

```
cannot find symbol for n here:
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sumOfArray(a, n));
```

How can I resolve this error?
Sorry I'm new to java TT TT

**Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySum {
  public static int sumOfArray(int[] a, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
      return a[n];
    } else {
      return sumOfArray(a, n - 1) + a[n];
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] a = new int[10];
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter the elements: ");
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
      a[n] = s.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sumOfArray(a, n));
  }
}
```

Comment: paste your whole code

Comment: `n` is declared in the scope of the for loop. Either declare it before the loop, or use `a.length` or `10` as the second parameter of `sumOfArray(a, n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have declared `n` inside `for`. It's scope is inside `for` loop only.

So instead of

```
for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
      a[n] = s.nextInt();
    }
```

use

```
int n;
for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
      a[n] = s.nextInt();
    }
```

It should do the work.

---

**Edit:**

As said by Andy Turner, it's better to use `a.length` instead of some constant. Because when you want to change the array size from `int[] a = new int[10]` to `int[] a = new int[20]`, you should also change it in the for loop. So, it's better to use the size of array in the for loop. Instead of `for(n=0; n< 10; n++)` use `for(n=0;n<a.length;n++)`.

`a.length` gives you the size of the array.

So you can change your code to:

```
for (int n = 0; n < a.length; n++) 
{
   a[n] = s.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Sum: " + sumOfArray(a, a.length));
```

Now you don't need to worry about changing the size in the for loop and while calling the `sum()`.

Comment: Nice explanation for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that n isn't in that scope. When you say for(int n;...) it means that n will only be available for the body of that loop. You are trying to print it outside the loop. You can declare n outside the loop :

```
int n;
for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
    a[n] = s.nextInt();
}
```